# android: programatically Is it possible to store Strings in keystore which is already available

Tags: android, credentials, android-keystore

I wanted to store a string in keystore which is a key for encryption of some data.
I'm already having that key as string I wrote that key in my code.but when I decompile my code the key is visible to me
So is there any solution for this problem
please help

Answer (score 0):

If its in your apk at all, it can be decompiled.  The only way to do it is to get it from some outside source-  download it from a server after authenticating with an outside password.  Or have the user type it in.  It can't be distributed as part of the app and remain safe.

Comment: But my app is offline one.not having any server conection to it.

Comment: @userI Then unless you get it from some other outside source, like a user providing it, its impossible.  You can't put it in your apk, which means you need to get it from someplace else.  Or depending on what it is, realize that your data probably isn't as secret as you think it is and stop caring.

Comment: suppose i retrieve the string from some other place for once then is it possible to store that string in keystore,instead of storing it in sqlite database or in sharedpreferences

Comment: Yes.  Once you get the key you can store it in the keystore.

Comment: will you please show me some piece of code for the same.

Comment: keyStore.setEntry(
     "mykey",
     new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey),
     new KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
             .setBlockMode(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
             .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
             .build());       and secrete key is string which i retrived from other place.Is it correct